# How complete list of object into another object uqing Rxjava

Tags: java, system.reactive

On a service, a client has on or many relationships.

Using rxjava when I get a client I want to retrieve from this client object a list of relationships.

Something like:

```
dataManager.getClient(clientId)
                    .zipWith(???)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe();
```

Comment: This question was very unclear. I tried to help with your English, spelling, and formatting, but I am afraid the question is still unclear. Please add details, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function to change the scope of the data within the observable:

```
dataManager.getClient(clientId)
            .map(client -> client.relationships)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(list -> {
                *Do Something*
            });
```